# Why isn't my PHP contact form working? (php newbie)

Tags: php, forms

From what I've learned, everything looks right in my contact.html file as well as my _contact.php file, but for some reason I keep getting a Chrome error message "...may be down or is configured incorrectly".

Here's code, and any help is appreciated.

Contact form in contact.html:

```
     <div class="ctext5">
    <br />
          <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="_contact.php">
  <table width="557" border="0" cellspacing="10">
      <tr>
        <th width="234" scope="row"><label for="firstname">First Name:</label></th>
        <td width="545"><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><label for="lastname">Last Name:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><label for="_email">E-Mail:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="_email" id="_email" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><label for="address">Address:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><label for="cityzip">City/Zip:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="cityzip" id="cityzip" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><label for="phone">Phone #:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th height="85" scope="row"><label for="comments">Questions / Other Information</label></th>
        <td><textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Code for _contact.php:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$_email = $_POST['_email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$cityzip = $_POST['cityzip'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = "From: $_email";
$to = 'email@domain.com';
$subject = 'Accurate Solutions Contact Form Submitted';
$message = "
First Name: $firstname \n
Last Name: $lastname \n
Phone: $phone \n
Address: $address \n
City/Zip: $cityzip \n
Email: $_email \n
Comments: $comments \n

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `"`, for one

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not do code debugging. You need to do your own debugging and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what is is actually doing including all error messages. Also, only provide your simplist use case. Don't post all of your code. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: syntax highlighting makes it a dead giveaway.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Thank you, and sorry. I was unaware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not closing your `$message` string. Try this:

```
$message = "
First Name: $firstname \n
Last Name: $lastname \n
Phone: $phone \n
Address: $address \n
City/Zip: $cityzip \n
Email: $_email \n
Comments: $comments \n";   //here the last double quote and the semicolon!

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse error

```
$message = "
First Name: $firstname \n
Last Name: $lastname \n
Phone: $phone \n
Address: $address \n
City/Zip: $cityzip \n
Email: $_email \n
Comments: $comments \n

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Should be

```
$message = "
First Name: $firstname \n
Last Name: $lastname \n
Phone: $phone \n
Address: $address \n
City/Zip: $cityzip \n
Email: $_email \n
Comments: $comments \n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = "
First Name: $firstname \n
Last Name: $lastname \n
Phone: $phone \n
Address: $address \n
City/Zip: $cityzip \n
Email: $_email \n
Comments: $comments \n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

You are missing the "; at the end of the message